# C# windows form browser control .DocumentCompleted event on .aspx pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, webbrowser-control

Before I go down the rabbit hole which is over my head and I would like to avoid for now… Is there a simple way to see if an online .aspx webpage loaded in the web browser control? .html pages work fine using .DocumentCompleted for me but .aspx visually loads fine but never triggers the DocumentCompleted event. I saw some good articles that mention the need of creating separate 3 threads and etc… unlike in those articles I am not interacting with the web application (the user is) I just want to hide a few irrelevant DIV elements on the side off the page.

Comment: You may consider using the new [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control instead - it's available as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user9938 Thank you! Unfortunately, I cannot mark your comment as an answer so I will post it for others here.

webview2 worked amazingly. On aspx pages **NavigationCompleted** still did not work however I was able to achieve this with **CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded**